# Travel while waiting for new passport as a new US citizen

Tags: passports, international-travel

My wife has her citizenship interview in late August. We are missionaries overseas and she needs to return overseas as soon as possible.

Would it be possible to do the interview, take the oath, apply for the US passport and then leave the country on her original passport? When her US passport arrives it can be brought to us with friends travelling two months later. Our next trip to the US she would have both passports to travel.

Is this possible? I am trying to book travel and not liking two one way tickets due to waiting it out.

Comment: Usually interview and an oath are not done at the same time.  Once you do an oath you can get a passport in 24 hours if it is so urgent.

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably don't know when the oath is, so you can't really buy tickets ahead of time for "right after the oath".

To answer your question, yes, nothing would prevent her from going to another country using her existing passport, and she will be able to come back to the US fine once she has her US passport.